# Two circles tangent in a point. Having two parallel segments on the circles find an isoscele triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I found the following problem.

> Have a circle with centre A and another with centre B. These circles are tangent in a point named T.
>
> P, N, B, Q are collinear points (N and Q are on second circle). P, M, A, R are collinear points (M and R are on first circle). A, T, B are collinear points. PRQ is a triangle.
>
> Prove that if $ MN\ ||\ RQ \Rightarrow \triangle PAB$  isosceles.

I also have the following figure:

[image: An example of a figure.]

Hope my english translation is intelligible!

I redrew the figure to have $ MN\ ||\ RQ $, but I have no idea how to solve that problem. I tried to find some relations with the MRQN trapezium and AB as its middle line but with no success.

[image: My draw.]

How can this be solved?

Thank you!

Comment: Your redrawing of the figure lost the fact that the two circles can have different radii.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right. But I can't figure out how to draw it right because else it doesn't look as an isosceles.

Comment: I think $Q$ needs to be higher on the right circle, which will bring point $P$ downward toward the circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem is false (see counterexample below). Are you sure the circles can have different radii?

[image]

EDIT, for those who don't believe their eyes.

Draw the two circles at will, tangent at $T$. Draw any diameter $MR$ in the circle of center $A$, then from $M$ and $R$ draw two lines parallel to $AB$. The intersections of these lines with the circle of center $B$ are the endpoints of two diameters: let $NQ$ be one of them. If lines $MR$ and $NQ$ meet at $P$, then triangles $PMN$, $PAB$, $PRQ$ are similar and $PA:PB=MA:NB$. Hence $PA=PB$ only if the circles have the same radii.

On the other hand, $AB=AP$ implies $MN=MP=TB$, and $MNBT$ is then a rhombus. We can then have $AB=AP$ only if $BT=MT$.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. This is false. Thanks. Yes, the problem says we have "two circles". It doesn't say anything about the radius.

Comment: It doesn't look false just from eyeballing the picture you provided, to me it looks like AB and AP are the same length. could you provide the data (angles for instance) of your picture? just showing a picture of a construction and claiming that it is a counter-example does not really prove anything in my oppinion.

Comment: ..actually if I measure the lengths of AB and AP using a ruler on the screen I measure the exact same length. I know that the picture might just be distorted, but it is the best I can do when you don't provide the data.

Comment: 1) "EDIT, for those who don't believe their eyes." Is a very rude way of dispelling a completely fair argument that I'm making.
2) You argue that PA = PB only when the circles have the same radii, and that is true, but the problem states nothing about the triangle PAB being isosceles with PA = PB, and not PA = AB or PB = AB.
3) Although your updated picture doesn't seem to show an isosceles triangle I would still not consider it a proof without any real data that can be verified. Without that it is nothing but a pretty picture.

Comment: Question: In your picture, the line RQ touches the small circle in two points, lets call the other point R', and likewise if you were to extend the line MN through the small circle then it two would touch the small circle in two points, lets call this other point M'. What happens if you draw the line PMAR so that it intersects the small circle in these other two points (R' and M') instead? I suspect that you would create an isosceles triangle with PA=AB, and this triangle would still be completely valid.